# Mail from Outlook to GMX: via Yahoo?

Tags: email, spam

On inspecting source of a clear scam mail I received, I noticed that the mail send from Outlook to GMX has somehow passed through Yahoo servers - how come? Is it some way to hide their original identity?

I have quoted few relevant parts below, and have tried to hide much fingerprints as possible.

> `Return-Path: <halima4love@outlook.com>
>   Received: from nm20-vm7.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com ([98.136.217.38]) by
>    mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx010) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 0MN5zM-1aNCcR17Ki-006bzd
>   Received: from [98.137.12.175] by nm20.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 11 Feb 2016 09:10:21 -0000
>   Received: from [98.137.12.215] by tm14.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 11 Feb 2016 09:10:21 -0000
>   Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1023.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 11 Feb 2016 09:10:21 -0000
>   X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
>   X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 430251.70760.bm@omp1023.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
>   Received: by ***.***.60.197; Thu, 11 Feb 2016 09:10:20 +0000 
>   Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 09:10:20 +0000 (UTC)
>   From: Joy Kones <halima4love@outlook.com>
>   Reply-To: Joy Kones <halima4love@outlook.com>
>   Subject: Hello dear ,
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   References: <**********.********.******1820586.JavaMail.yahoo.ref@mail.yahoo.com>
>   Content-Length: 928
>   Envelope-To: <hidden>
>   X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
>   X-GMX-Antivirus: 0 (no virus found)
>   X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;`

Quick search did not return any duplicates, please do tell me if you find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message wasn't sent from outlook.com, it the spammer just claims that it was – there is generally little protection against forged data in mails.

It looks like the mail originated from Yahoo and was delivered to GMX from there.  Outlook was not involved in the process, an outlook.com address was just used as the sender address.

Comment: thank you. That's what I was looking for. Sorry for late reply!  I am pretty perplexed by the migration-rejection-closing drama, sorry I am deleting my post!